# Encoding binary data in flask/jinja2

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, flask, jinja2

Hello I'm developing small app in python using flask, jinja2, sqlalchemy,...
I'm saving binare data in my database:

```
file = request.files['file']
# store the recipe
recipe = Recipe(None, session['user_in'], request.form['title'], request.form['text'],request.form['tags'], file.read())
db.session.commit()
```

and i want to show the entry in my app:

```
@app.route('/recipe/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_entry(id):
  return render_template('show_entry.html', entry=db_session.query(Recipe).get(id))
```

And in my template i have:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ entry.image }}"/>
```

But i have unicode error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can you help me how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data:image/png;base64,` says that the PNG data is base64 encoded, so I think that you need to base64 encode the image data before rendering the template. If you do that, the encoding error should go away. Something like this should do the trick:

```
@app.route('/recipe/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show_entry(id):
  entry = db_session.query(Recipe).get(id)
  entry.image = entry.image.encode('base64')
  return render_template('show_entry.html', entry=entry)
```

I'm not overly familiar with this, it could be a dict lookup?, i.e.

```
entry['image'] = entry['image'].encode('base64')
```

Comment: @Cospel - No problem. Which is the correct syntax - attribute reference or dict lookup?

Comment: +1. But `entry` seems to be an OR mapped object, so modifying `entry.image` would actually change the object in the database (if the transaction were to be committed). So I'd probably just do `render_template('show_entry.html', img=entry.image.encode('base64'))` and use `img` in the template.

Comment: @mhawke dotted attribute access is in fact the way to access columns in SQLAlchemy. But it seems the OP got the gist of your answer already, so this is just FYI if you want to make your answer match the circumstances a bit better.